# SugarCRM, Getting Current Logged in User Details through AJAX Call

Tags: authentication, sugarcrm

I have written a custom PHP file to be called from AJAX request for SugarCRM. However, when I try to print

```
global $current_user;

print_r($current_user);
```

It prints blank values with all the fields listed in the array like below.

```
User Object
(
    [name] => 
    [full_name] => 
    [id] => 
    [user_name] => 
    [user_hash] => 
    [salutation] => 
    [first_name] => 
    [last_name] => 
    [date_entered] => 
    [date_modified] => 
    [modified_user_id] => 
    [created_by] => 
    [created_by_name] => 
    [modified_by_name] => 
    [description] => 
    [phone_home] => 
    [phone_mobile] => 
    [phone_work] => 
    [phone_other] => 
    [phone_fax] => 
    [email1] => 
    [email2] => 
    [address_street] => 
    [address_city] => 
    [address_state] => 
    [address_postalcode] => 
    [address_country] => 
    [status] => 
    [title] => 
    [portal_only] => 0
    [department] => 
    [authenticated] => 
    [error_string] => 
    [is_admin] => 0
    [employee_status] => 
    [messenger_id] => 
    [messenger_type] => 
    [is_group] => 
    [accept_status] => 
    [team_id] => 
    [receive_notifications] => 1
    [default_team] => 
    [reports_to_name] => 
    [reports_to_id] => 
    [team_exists] => 
    [table_name] => users
    [module_dir] => Users
    [object_name] => User
    [user_preferences] => 
    [importable] => 1
```

.....

I have searched in SugarCRM Forums but no use. I suspect the reason could be valid entry point is not defined in my custom page, as don't understand how to define except the following methods

```
if(!defined('sugarEntry'))define('sugarEntry', true);
  if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point'); 
  require_once('include/entryPoint.php');
```

Comment: Is this for a SugarCRM 7.x installation or for SugarCRM 6.x?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is way back 2013, thought of sharing :)

this happens when you call

```
global $current_user;
```

outside sugarcrm, an option I made is create a hook in custom User module and access $current_user variable  there and only fetch those needed values, maybe save on a session?, depends on you.

Hope this helps anyone :)

**SAMPLE OF WHAT I DID**

Create a file **custom_external_session.php**

```
<?php if(!defined('sugarEntry') ||!sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');
class custom_external_session {
     function get_current_user(& $focus, $event, $arguments){
          global $current_user;
          $user_id = $current_user->id;
          session_start();
          $_SESSION["custom_current_user"] =  $user_id;
     }
}
```

- upload this file to /var/www/html/sugarcrm/custom/modules/Users/

**note: /var/www/html/sugarcrm/ -> this varies to where you put sugarcrm**

- then on that folder **(/custom/modules/Users/)**, edit logic_hooks.php then add this code

  ```
  $hook_array['after_login'][] = Array(5, 'custom_external_session', 'custom/modules/Users/custom_external_session.php', 'custom_external_session', 'get_current_user');
  ```
- you can now use this: **$_SESSION["custom_current_user"]** to get the current user_id, then you can play with it is record, might as well edit or add more information on the saved session, say you want the fullname etc, just do it under custom_external_session. I'm not sure if there is a better way working with external codes
- remember to always **RELOGIN** when you edit the custom_external_session, so values will be updated.

hope this is much clearer to you.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to load it from js side

```
var userBean = app.data.createBean("Users", { id: app.user.id });
userBean.fetch({
         success:function(userData){
          //everything you need will be on userData
          }
});
```